# What is the angle of triangle PQR

Tags: linear-algebra

$P(1,1,1)$

$Q(0,3,2)$

$R(2,1,6)$

The question is: what is the angle of triangle PQR?

Solution:

$PQ=(-1,2,1)$

$QR=(2,-2,4)$

$PR=(1,0,6)$

$PQ \times QR = 10i+6j-2k$ (found by taking the cross product)

$|| PQ \times QR || = \sqrt{10^2+6^2+(-2)^2}=2\sqrt{35}$

However, I don't understand how an angle is just $2\sqrt{35}$

I thought that the angle would be found by doing $\frac{u \circ v}{||u||||v||}=\cos\theta$?

And furthermore, I don't even think I understand the question. What does it mean to find the angle of a triangle? Don't triangles have three angles?

Answer (score 1):

- Should use dot product, since (at most one) interior angle of a triangle might be obtused.  Beware of the order of the vectors.

$$\angle PQR =\cos^{-1} \frac{\vec{QP} \cdot \vec{QR}}{(QP)(QR)}$$

- To find all interior angles of a triangle, simply using cosine law is good enough.
- $\dfrac{1}{2} \vec{PQ} \times \vec{QR}$ can be regarded as a vector area of $\Delta PQR$.

Comment: so does this mean that the question is wrong?

Comment: It depends or you can describe more context.  For instance, which chapter of the question came from or whether the solution is an official one.